# Any standard technique to handle file modification using separate application?

Tags: java, file, version-control, repository

I have a Java application that manages different files a updates them when necessary. It uses Git under the hood to pull updates from the main server.
To restrict a user from messing with the files inside the repository, I plan to hide repository in some system folder with restricted access rights or maybe even proprietary archive.

Sometimes a user needs to pull a file from the repository, modify it and push it back. To archive this, I want to copy a file to a temporary location, open this copy with the corresponding application and then save it back when the user had finished it's modification.

The algorithm would look like this:

- select a file
- copy to a temporary folder
- open with an assigned application
- ??? - wait for the file change / notify main application on "Save"/"Save As ..".
- push modified version back into repository/archive
- delete temporary copy

I am looking for a "wait for a change -> notify main app" mechanism. I suppose some kind of hook already exists.

At this point, nothing better than "Let's integrate Word and Acrobat into our app" or "Let's write some low-level file system driver" comes to mind. Both would be hard to support and maintain.

Comment: It looks like what I need.

Comment: "To restrict a user from messing with the files inside the repository" ... how is your app able to do that? Does it validate the changes a user made? I also wonder why your app tries to re-invent the wheel. Wouldn't it be enough to let users use that Git repo directly, but prohibit history changes? When someone messed with a file, then someone is still able to fix that. I don't see how your app adds a valuable layer here.

Comment: @Tom Git does not work here with it's commits because, while all the files are indeed pulled from the central repository, they would be pushed to a different one. Each file is an electronic form (pdf-form, report) that periodically need to be filled and then pushed back to the office. It means that if there is a report that need to be filled each day, there would be 365 copies of the original report (template), each filled with different data. Size of each report is higher that several MBs, so I don't send 365 copies, but create 365 binary DIFFs between original and modified and send them.

Comment: @Tom A typical user is a marine officer with low computer skills and too much free time to explore his laptop (laptop is not his property, but is owned by a company). A typical problem is that a user simply saves (copies) original reports to the desktop and keeps filling them instead of using updated ones in the corresponding folder. Time has proven that it is pointless to try to reason them. Sometimes they just delete this files altogether cause of an error. Because satellite internet is very expansive, you can't organize a quick repair so the the system has be as automatic as possible.